# Used Windows Media Player with visual studio 2010 but it not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-media-player

i have used the Windows media player in visual studio 2010 but it can not run and give the following error. How can i solve these error i also change my build setting from X86 to AnyCPU
but till it don't work.
The error is following "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" 
    xmlns:ax="clr-namespace:AxWMPLib;assembly=AxInterop.WMPLib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="winfromhost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405" Panel.ZIndex="200" >
            <ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="AxWMP"></ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can use the API. To do this:

1. Right click anywhere in the toolbox
2. In the **COM Components** tab, select **Windows Media Player**
3. In the toolbox, there should now be a Windows Media Player item.

Using this method makes it much easier and saves a lot of time, if there are any problems take a look at [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Hope this helps.

Comment: i already add windows media player in user control.....but above error can run the programe.....